# Using proc iml to do monte carlo integration

Tags: sas, montecarlo, sas-iml

```
proc iml;

call randseed(4545); * initialize the stream (like streaminit);
x = J(5000,1,.); * pre-allocate space for random numbers;
call randgen(x,'normal',0,1); * fill x with N(0,1) deviates;
y = y + (x**2 - 3*x**3 + 5x < 1);
p = y / 5000;  * MEAN acts on each matrix column;
se = sqrt(y*(1-y)/5000); * VAR, but not STD or STDERR, also acts on columns;
print "IML STEP: estimated probability is" p
"with standard error" se;  * use PRINT, not PUT;
```

I'm trying to use monte carlo integration with proc iml to estimate the probability that x**2 - 3*x**3 + 5x is less than 1. What am I doing wrong? Do loops are not allowed by the way.

Comment: I guess the bigger question where would be, how do I make the (x**2 - 3*x**3 + 5x < 1) count into a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things wrong here.  AS Rick says, this has the feel of a homework problem, so I won't post the solution.  Here are some things to think about.

1. A normal trial is probably not what you are looking for.  Your function is defined on the entire number line.  Getting a x~N(0,1) where abs(x) > 3 is not likely.
2. Rick mentions that you are using y before defining it.
3. Look at element wise operations instead of matrix operations.  Use these in your function.
4. `5x` is not a valid operation.
5. Consider set reduction [:] to do the mean.
6. I don't think your equation for the SE is correct.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a homework problem, so I am not going to give the complete answer. However, my first hint is to think about what Y is supposed to be. It is supposed to be an indicator variable (0/1) that indicates whether a randomly chosen observation falls within a certain region of the plane.

My second hint is to remember that you cannot use an undefined variable on the right hand side of an expression, so 'y + (f(x)<1)' is not a valid vector expression.  Good luck!